# Advanced use of the Jersey resource model: variable annotation for entity

Tags: jersey-2.0

I need to use the programmatic API to build a Jersey resource method and define its handling method/class/inflector. At the end, the resource should look like something like this:

```
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

  @POST
  @Consumes("text/plain")
  public String getHello(
    @CustomEntityAnnotation("World") CustomEntityClass name) {
      return "Hello " + name.toString() +  "!";
  }
}
```

But I need to build many such resources with different values for paths and more importantly: different values for the `@CustomEntityAnnotation` annotation.

Let me add that this annotation must later be accessed by a `ContainerResponseFilter`, and by a `MessageBodyWriter<CustomEntityClass>`.

Unfortunately, I can't find in the docs where I shall add this annotation to the resource Method model builder, and what should be the signature of the method handler.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Maxime